# How can I apply the Hamiltonian function and Pontryagin's maximum principle in the context of Optimal Control Theory?

Tags: economics, optimal-control, hamilton-equations

I am really struggling to grasp how the Hamiltonian Function and Pontryagin's Maximum Principle work in the context of Optimal Control Theory (Maths for Economics) course. I am given the following conditions:

$$
\quad\space\max_{u} \mathcal{F} = \int_{t_0}^{t_f} f(x(t), u(t), t) \, dt + S(x_f) \tag{1.1}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{l}
  \dot x(t) = g(x(t),u(t),t) \\
  x(t_i)=x_i \\
  x(t_f)=x_f \\
\end{array}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{array}{l}
\text(constraints) \\
\text(known) \\
\text(unknown) \\
\end{array} 
\tag{1.2}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{l}
  \overline{x} = x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) \\
  \overline{u} = u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n) \\
  \overline{g} = g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n) \\
\end{array}
\end{cases}
\qquad\quad
\begin{array}{l}
\text(state \space variables) \\
\text(control \space variables) \\
\text(constraint \space functions) \\
\end{array} 
\tag{1.3}
$$

So far I understand that we construct the *Hamiltonian* $\mathcal{H}$ from the *Hamiltonian Functional* $\mathcal{L}$ and the *costate functions* $\lambda$ such that:

$$
\mathcal{H}(x,u,t,\lambda) = f(x,u,t) + {\lambda}(g(x,u,t)) \tag{2.1}
$$

Then, we find the Hamiltonian equations for the *state* $x$ and *costate* $\lambda$ variables:

$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial \lambda} \\
\dot{x}_i = \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial x_i} \quad \text{for} \quad n > 1
\end{cases}
\tag{3.1}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{\lambda} = -\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial x} \\
\dot{\lambda}_i = -\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial x_i} \quad \text{for} \quad n > 1
\lambda_f = \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial x_f} S(x_f)
\end{cases}
\tag{3.2}
$$

We are then instructed to solve using Pontryagin's Maximum Principle:

$$
\text{If } m = 1 \begin{cases}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial u} = 0\\
\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{H}}{\partial u^2} < 0 \\
\end{cases}
\tag{4.1}
$$

$$
\text{If } m > 1 \begin{cases}
\nabla \mathcal{H} = \overline{0} \\
\nabla^2 \mathcal{H} < 0 \quad \text{for} \quad \text{odd } |M_H| \\
\nabla^2 \mathcal{H} > 0 \quad \text{for} \quad \text{even } |M_H| \\
\end{cases}
\tag{4.2}
$$

Finally, we are told that if we only have the initial conditions $x(t) = x_i$, then:

$$
\begin{cases}
x(t_i) = x_i \\
\lambda(t_f) = \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial x_f} S(x_f) \quad \text{(transversality condition)} \\
\end{cases}
\tag{5.1}
$$

While, if we have both initial and boundary conditions, then:

$$
\begin{cases}
x(t_i) = x_i \\
x(t_f) = x_f \\
\end{cases}
\tag{5.2}
$$

I fail to understand the following points:

- In the Hamiltonian equations for the state variables **3.1**, where did the second equation come from and how did it go from being the derivative of $\mathcal{H}$ with respect to $\lambda$ to being the derivative of $\mathcal{H}$ with respect to $\mathcal{x_i}$? Shoulnd't it derivate with respect to $\lambda$ as well?
- In the Hamiltonian equations for the costate variables **3.2**, where does $\lambda_f$ come from? When is it used?
- In equations **4.1** and **4.2**, what does $m$ stand for? I understand from my professors lectures that it means *multiplicity*, but in a different sense than when used, for example, to talk about eigenvalues in the context of dynamical systems. What, then, is it alluding to?
- In equation **5.1**, what is the *transversality condition*, and when/how is it applied? Why is it not necessary when boundary conditions are present, as shown in **5.2**?

Overall, I am currently unable to solve this kind of problem. Any help  understanding how to approach it would be greatly appreciated. As a quick sidenote, any appropiate criticism on the formatting of this post and my usage of LaTex would also be appreciated.